# what do upper_bound() do?

Tags: c++, algorithm, upperbound

I am begineer and I dont understand the following.

In the code
[image: code]

I got the output

[image: output]

Now my question is since the `upper_bound()` operator gives the index of greater value how did the output gave the answer of upperbound as 7 and not 1.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, or output. Place everything required in the question as text.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). And why don't just read [`std::upper_bound`'s documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rationale for std::lower\_bound and std::upper\_bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554509/rationale-for-stdlower-bound-and-stdupper-bound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` functions require the range to be partitioned according to the value you are looking for, essentially being sorted. Since your vector does not meet this criterion, you cannot expect logical results.