# Binary searching for a vector<int> in vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, lower-bound, upperbound

I have a vector `events`, which consists of vector of events, such as:

```
events = [[1,3,2],[2,4,3],[4,5,2],[10,20,8]]
```

where `events[i]` is of the format `[startTime_i, endTime_i, value_i]` (inclusive).  All the events are sorted in such a way that `j`th event appears after `i`th, if `startTime_j > startTime_i`.

Since the events are sorted, I want to use binary search (`lower_bound()`) to find out the next non-overlapping event that I could attend after the current one.

A friend suggested using:

```
vector<int> v={events[i][1]+1,INT_MIN,INT_MIN};
auto nextOne=lower_bound(begin(events),end(events),v);
```

I don't follow the intuition behind setting the 2nd and 3rd values to `INT_MIN` above. Could someone please explain?  If I had to get an `upper_bound()`, would I have to use `INT_MAX` instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @user17732522, no problem.  Could you please guide me?

Comment: The optional fourth parameter to `lower_bound` allows you to provide a custom comparator. That custom comparator could just compare the first element of the vector and ignore the other two. But the default comparator will compare all the elements of the vector. So using `INT_MIN` is a way to make sure that `v` compares smaller than a real event vector when the start times are equal.

Comment: @RKarandikar Its just to make sure that you find an item with the first entry equal to `events[i][1]+1`. As mentioned above, a cleaner solution would be a custom comparator that ignores the fields which shouldn't be relevant to the ordering.

Comment: @user3386109, why do we want to compare _smaller_ than a real event vector?

Comment: Because you're looking for the lower bound. If there are multiple events with the same start time, and `v` compares smaller than some, and larger than others, then `lower_bound` will return an index in the middle of those vectors, not the index of the first.

Comment: @user3386109, ah, that makes sense.  So by that logic, if we are using `upper_bound()`, we will have to use `INT_MAX` to return the largest, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, provided we agree that `upper_bound()` returns the index of the first element of an array whose value is greater than the value being searched. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554509/rationale-for-stdlower-bound-and-stdupper-bound) may help you understand what I tried to say there :)

Comment: For a given `i` you wish to find the smallest `j` for which `start_time_j >= end_time_i`. Correct?

Comment: Instead of `{events[i][1]+1,INT_MIN,INT_MIN}` for starttime, endtime and value you could use `v={events[i][1]+1,events[i][1]+1,0}`, as the end time is at least the start time and the value is at least 0, is it? When finding an element, the first field starttime has the highest priority, the endtime the second highest priority and the value the least priority. We want to find the event, which fulfills the starttime, but is the first in the two other categories/fields. The +1 assumes that the times are integers and the next event starts at least +1 after the end of the previous event.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a little bit on your sorting criteria.

You mentioned that the only criterium is "if startTime_j > startTime_i". So a comparison operator for your "Event" struct could be like:

```
// Simple comparison operator
bool operator < (const Event& other) const { return startTime < other.startTime; }
```

Only the start Time is taken as criterium for the comparison. In such case, INT_MIN and INT_MIN are just dummies. They will not be used in any comparison for `std::lower_bound`. And I guess, it is like that because of the first parameter in the "search event". Look at

```
events[i][1]+1,INT_MIN,INT_MIN
```

Here we build one Event, wit some dummy value (INT_MIN) for the "endTime" and "value" and with a start time, that is one bigger than the end time of `events[i]`

To repeat. This means: We search for the next event, where the "startTime" is higer then the "endTime" of the current element.

Example, if the current element is 1,3,2, then the end time is 3. So, if we do not want to have an overlap, we need to look for some element with a start time >= 3+1. And this will be 4,5,2.

That is rather intuitive. And, as said, INT_MIN is just a dummy. It will not be used.

To illustrate how this could work, please see and run the below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Event {
    int startTime{};
    int endTime{};
    int value{};

    // Simple comparison operator
    bool operator < (const Event& other) const { return startTime < other.startTime; }

    // Simple overwrite of inserter operator for easy output
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Event& e) {
        return os << e.startTime << ' ' << e.endTime << ' ' << e.value;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Main Test data
    std::vector<Event> events{ {2,4,3}, {1,3,2},{10,20,8},{4,5,2}};
    std::cout << "\nOriginal:\n";  
    for (const Event& e : events) std::cout << e << '\n';

    // Sort, if not yet sorted
    std::sort(events.begin(), events.end());
    std::cout << "\nSorted:\n";
    for (const Event& e : events) std::cout << e << '\n';

    // For test purposes: Search the next none overlapping event for each event
    for (const Event& e : events) {

        // Build the search event. It shall not overlap. So the start time of the next
        // must be greater than the end time of this
        Event searchEvent = e;
        searchEvent.startTime = e.endTime + 1;

        // Now search the
        std::cout << "\n\nLooking for the next none overlapping element after: " << e << '\n';

        std::vector<Event>::iterator next = std::lower_bound(events.begin(), events.end(), searchEvent);
        if (next != events.end()) {
            std::cout << "Found at index " << std::distance(events.begin(), next) << "   --> " << *next << '\n';
        }
        else std::cerr << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is only a dummy, if a custom comparison operator is used

Comment: Yes, correct. This is my assumption from what I read.